# How to get the value of lat long from a HDF file?

Tags: python, gdal, hdf

I'm trying to get the value of a latitude and longitude from a subdataset of a HDF [file](ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/6/MOD13Q1/2017/321/MOD13Q1.A2017321.h31v10.006.2017337222145.hdf) using gdal. But I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: index -62399 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4800
```

Here's my code:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr,gdal

hdf_file = gdal.Open("MOD13Q1.A2017321.h31v10.006.2017337222145.hdf")
subDatasets = hdf_file.GetSubDatasets()
val_dict = {}
#print subDatasets[0]
dataset = gdal.Open(subDatasets[1][0])
transf = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
success,transfInv = gdal.InvGeoTransform(transf)
ds = dataset.ReadAsArray()
#lon,lat = -17.586972, 139.158043
lat = -16.718853 
lon = 142.645773
px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(transfInv, lon, lat)

value = ds[int(px),int(py)]
print value
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the geotransform (`transf`) of the dataset you can see that the coordinates are not in degrees lat/lon (its Sinusoidal).

Therefore you shouldn't provide lat/lon values when applying the geotransform to convert to pixel coordinates. These values should be in the same projection as the dataset.

For example, if you enter the coordinates of the upper-left corner, you will get (0,0) as a result:

```
mapx = transf[0]
mapy = transf[3]
px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(transfInv, mapx, mapy)
```

Or for the lower-right corner:

```
mapx = transf[0] + transf[1] * ds.shape[1]
mapy = transf[3] + transf[5] * ds.shape[0]
px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(transfInv, mapx, mapy)
```

Which results in (4800, 4800).